# Finding a shared identifier for a Bluetooth peripheral across both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I'm recently developing native apps on iOS and Android that handle Bluetooth BLE devices.

For iOS i use **CoreBluetooth** and Android **BluetoothDevice**

When the BLE device is found, it can be identified on Android using the MAC Address, and on iOS using the device's UUID.

The example package returned for the same device are the following:

**iOS**

```
    CBPeripheral: 0x1700ff880, 
    identifier = A3D26155-414C-4940-8EB9-C754AD202B64, //UUID
    name = DEVICE01,
    state = disconnected
```

**Android**

```
    mDevice=00:18:31:84:37:E5, //MAC ADDRESS
    mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6,
    mServiceUuids=[0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb],
    mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={},
    mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=DEVICE01],
    mRssi=-58,
    mTimestampNanos=5196365700642
```

The problem is that I can not recognize the same device between the two platforms, because in iOS the identifier is the UUID, whereas in Android the identifier is the MAC ADDRESS.

I have been looking at how to access the MAC ADDRESS on iOS and say it is not allowed for security issues, while the UUID on Android does not have a value similar to iOS.

Is there any possibility of accessing some common data between both platforms?

***NOTE:** It is clear that the device name is repeated on all devices and is not a variable used as an identifier.*

Comment: Do you find solution ? I'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to have the peripheral advertise some custom unique identifier other than the Bluetooth device address.

You can for example have that each device has a unique name or use the service data or manufacturer specific data fields.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS allocate UUID to peripheral, so different iOS device allocate different UUID to peripheral. We can not change in UUID in iOS.
Not any data was same in android and iOS for identify.
Try with RSSI range. I think both device get same range(RSSI) value of peripheral.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can't use the RSSI, because the devices are not searching at the same time, and not in the same range... I'm still trying ton find out how to resolve it